# What's with the big blank div on the sidebar under HMP/Announcements?

Tags: bug, design, sidebar

Recently there's a big blank spot underneath the HMP/Announcements box. This looks like a new `div.js-sidebar-zone` with `min-height: 735px` applied, but nothing seems to be put in it. Can this be fixed/rolled back, please? I would prefer to not scroll a bunch just to see similar questions, or HNQ if I have it enabled.

(NB: I get this problem even with no addons running such as Stylus, *Monkey, or uBlock Origin)

Dark mode example:

> [image: dark mode]

and Light mode example:

> [image: light mode]

Comment: It’s the «Looking for a job?» box that’s supposed to go there. It shows up in the sidebar (bottom) on my phone, in desktop mode.

Comment: Just adblock it, nothing useful shows up there anyway.

Comment: @Andreas Interesting. I zapped "Job Recommendations" from the profile page. Maybe there's a connection.

Comment: @Andreas It doesn't show up for me even when I don't have any addons running.

Comment: It is where the Hotter Questions go. None were found ...

Comment: Did you check for other issues in the web inspector? JS? Could it be the powers of Stack have been unleashed?

Comment: No repro for me on Chrome. I guess it's an A-B test?

Comment: The posts are too hot. You have to keep the other div a safe distance away from them to prevent melting.

Comment: Is this being fixed? I don't need a `min-height: 735px` blank section of the `js-sidebar-zone` on a 900px display. That looks horribly awkward. It always worked right (well at least for the past 5-years) until mid-August 2020. What changed?